# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy_utils'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I installed SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy_Utils but then I run uvicorn main:app --reload it gives me an error.

```py
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from config import host, user, password, db_name, port
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

url = f'postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}'
    if not database_exists(url):
        create_database(url)

    engine = create_engine(url, pool_size=50, echo=True)

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Here's the errors I get

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy_utils'
```

I`ve tried to reinstall sqlalchemy and upgraded python, nothing works :c

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you

Comment: @ShadowCrafter_01 added code that uses sqlalchemy utils

Comment: Try `python -m pip install` instead of just `pip install`

Comment: That's not yet a minimal, reproducible example. Where are `create_engine`  and `sessionmaker` defined?

Comment: @Squarish does not work(

Comment: Maybe you were installing  `pip install sqlalchemy_utils` instead of `pip install sqlalchemy-utils`?

Comment: @ArtemStrogin tried, still nothing

Comment: py -m pip install SQLAlchemy --upgrade

Comment: Released: May 19, 2023